# Exiting While Loop

Tags: mysql, while-loop

I am trying to read values from a MySql database and check whether the id that needs to be updated, already exists in database or not. I have been able to make everything else in the program work except the part of checking database. Here is some of my code:

```
public void updateStatement() throws SQLException{
    try
    {
        connnectDatabse();
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Could not connect to database..");
    }

    System.out.println("How many entries would you like to update?");
    kb=new Scanner(System.in);
    int numEntries = kb.nextInt();
    int counter =0;
    String newName=null, newDepartment =null;
    int newSalary=0, newId =0;

    int counterValues =0;
    while(counterValues != numEntries){

        System.out.println("Please enter 5 to view current entries in database\n");
        selectStatement();
        int idToUpdate =0;
        boolean idVerify =false;

        //Check if the user id exists in database or not
        while(!(idVerify)){
            System.out.println("\nPlease enter the ID of the record to update");
            idToUpdate = kb.nextInt();
            idFoundInDatabase(idArrayList, idToUpdate);

        }

        System.out.println("Please choose the number of column to update from below options.\n1.ID\n2.Name\n3.Salary\n4.Department");
        int columnToUpdate = kb.nextInt();
        switch(columnToUpdate){
        case 1:
            System.out.println("What will be the new id value for the selected ID?");
            newId = kb.nextInt();
            query = "update employee set ID = ? where ID = ?";

            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("What will be the new name for the selected ID?");
            newName = kb.next();
            query = "update employee set Name = ? where ID = ?";
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("What will be the new salary for the selected ID?");
            newSalary = kb.nextInt();
            query = "update employee set Salary = ? where ID = ?";
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("What will be the new department for the selected ID?");
            newDepartment = kb.next();
            query = "update employee set Department = ? where ID = ?";
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Correct option not chosen");
        }

        PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(query);

        if(columnToUpdate ==1){
            st.setInt(1, newId);
            st.setInt(2, idToUpdate);
        }

        else if(columnToUpdate ==2){
            st.setString(1, newName);
            st.setInt(2, idToUpdate);
        }
        else if(columnToUpdate ==3){
            st.setInt(1, newSalary);
            st.setInt(2, idToUpdate);
        }
        else{
            st.setString(1, newDepartment);
            st.setInt(2, idToUpdate);
        }
        //execute the prepared statement
        st.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("Record successfully updated..");
        counterValues++;
    }
}
   //Code that I am unable to exit. This is 
    a separate method outside of updateStatement() method. 
   ArrayList contains the list of ids that are already in the database. ArrayList has been populated successfully.

 public boolean idFoundInDatabase(ArrayList<String> arrayList, int id){


    boolean validId = false;
    while(validId == true){
        String idRead = String.valueOf(id);
        for (int i=0; i<arrayList.size(); i++){
            String elementRead =arrayList.get(i);
            if(elementRead.equals(idRead)){
                validId = true;
                break;
            }
            else{
                validId= false;
            }
        }
    }
    return validId;
}

}
```

If required I am also posting the lines of code where I get the result set to make the array list of ids.

```
 while(result.next()){
            String id =result.getString("ID");
            idArrayList.add(id);
            if(choice == 1 || choice == 2 || choice == 3 || choice == 4){
                resultIs = result.getString(columnName);
                System.out.println(resultIs);                   
            }
            else{
                System.out.println(result.getString("ID")+"\t"+result.getString("Name")+
                        "\t"+result.getString("Salary")+"\t"+result.getString("Department") );
            }
        }
```

Problem is exiting the above idFoundInDatabase method. It identifies if the id which user wants to update is in the database or not. On finding even the correct id which exists in the database, it just keeps on reading the values in array list, instead of going to return statement. Am I also doing something wrong where I call this method? Any help will be appreciated. Have been stuck on it for almost a day now. Have done debugging many many times. I am doing this just to get acquainted with jdbc and parameterized queries, so that I can follow the similar thing in a bigger project.Any help is appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: I suspect the error is in the condition on your while loop - as it's currently written the idFoundInDatabase function will always return false without running the body of the loop

Comment: where is `idArrayList` coming from? you probably shouldn't be looping through an array to check the id, you should be asking the database if it exists. if you must loop, change `while(validId == true)` to `while(validId == false)`

Comment: @pala idArrayList comes from reading the values of id column retrieved from result set. Changing the condition to while(validId == false), it goes into an infinite loop as validId was initialized to false to begin with.

Comment: actually, you dont need the `while` loop at all - get rid of it. just iterating once over the arraylist will be sufficient

Comment: @pala I just added my whole code for checking. So remove the while loop?

Comment: yes, i dont see a need for it.

Comment: So should I do something like this? Iterator<String> iterator = arrayList.iterator();
  while (iterator.hasNext()) {
   iterator.next();
  }

Comment: @pala_ any hints as to how not to use the while loop?

Comment: just delete this line `while(validId == true){` and then the `}` immediately before `return validId;`

Comment: @pala_ Thanks for the hint mate. Now it does go through loop correctly but now it gives problem in the while loop within the updateStatement() method where that method was invoked i.e within the while(!(idVerify)) loop. Does that need to go to? Appreciate your help so far. Think it is close. I need to keep prompting user to enter a valid id to check against the values in the array list. That is why I think that  while(!(idVerify)) should be needed. Your thoughts?

Comment: can you repost with your updated code? you only need to remove the `while` loop in the `idFoundInDatabase` method.

Comment: @pala_ Hi..it is already posted above. I am updating the while loop that I changed in the  idFoundInDatabase() method as per your suggestion. Bu t the other while loop in updateStatement() method is posted above. What is happening now is that after verifying that correct id was found in the idFoundInDatabase method, it goes back to the updateStatement method while loop and again asks "Please enter the ID of the record to update" and again run  method idFoundInDatabase, instead it should exit out of while(!(idVerify))  loop and go to line System.out.println("Please choose the number of column..

Comment: you are returning `validId` from `idFoundInDatabase()` but you are not capturing and using it.  change `idFoundInDatabase(idArrayList, idToUpdate);` to `idVerify =  idFoundInDatabase(idArrayList, idToUpdate);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

Your `while` loop inside of `idFoundInDatabase()` is not necessary - one simple iteration through the `for` loop over `arrayList` is enough.

You are returning a boolean value from that function, but your calling method does not capture and use it, so `idVerify` is never being changed from `false` to `true`, so your input loop repeats forever.

All you need to do sort that out is change `idFoundInDatabase(idArrayList, idToUpdate);` to `idVerify = idFoundInDatabase(idArrayList, idToUpdate);` and then your input loop should successfully terminate when a valid id is found.

Comment: Completely forgot about that. It works!! Thank you very much for your help. I should be able to add more functionality to this now. Thank you very much once again.